Error occurs when accessing Object storage file from Watson studio
I try to read and analyze (as a course assignment) file stored in IBM Cloud Object Storage from a Jupyter notebook in IBM Watson studio. But when I run the code I received Credential Retrieval Error.
When I created a new project (advanceddatasciencecapstone) in Watson studio, new bucket and related service credentials were auto-generated (one as Viewer: WDP-Viewer-advanceddatasciencecapstone-donotdelete-pr-lwh86peri7odfg, one as Editor: WDP-Editor-advanceddatasciencecapstone-donotdelete-pr-lwh86peri7odfg). I uploaded my csv file to same bucket.
Then I use this code to access csv file from Jupyter notebook (It also stored in same bucket).
import ibm_boto3
from ibm_botocore.client import Config, ClientError
import pandas as pd

COS_ENDPOINT = "https://control.cloud-object-storage.cloud.ibm.com/v2/endpoints"
COS_API_KEY_ID = "#########################"
COS_INSTANCE_CRN = "#####################################################::"
BUCKET_NAME = "advanceddatasciencecapstone-donotdelete-pr-lwh86peri7odfg"
CSV_FILE_NAME = "##############################"

cos_resource = ibm_boto3.resource("s3",
    ibm_api_key_id=COS_API_KEY_ID,
    ibm_service_instance_id=COS_INSTANCE_CRN,
    config=Config(signature_version="s3v4"),
    endpoint_url=COS_ENDPOINT
)

csv_object = cos_resource.Object(BUCKET_NAME, CSV_FILE_NAME)

df = pd.read_csv(csv_object.get()['Body'])

print(df.head())

I used Credentials of "WDP-Editor-advanceddatasciencecapstone-donotdelete-pr-lwh86peri7odfg" (Above mentioned which auto generated when creating the Project) was used to fill COS_API_KEY_ID and COS_INSTANCE_CRN. After running code i get error like this
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
CredentialRetrievalError                  Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[3], line 20
     11 cos_resource = ibm_boto3.resource("s3",
     12     ibm_api_key_id=COS_API_KEY_ID,
     13     ibm_service_instance_id=COS_INSTANCE_CRN,
     14     config=Config(signature_version="s3v4"),
     15     endpoint_url=COS_ENDPOINT
     16 )
     18 csv_object = cos_resource.Object(BUCKET_NAME, CSV_FILE_NAME)
---> 20 df = pd.read_csv(csv_object.get()['Body'])
     22 print(df.head())

File /opt/conda/envs/Python-RT23.1/lib/python3.10/site-packages/ibm_boto3/resources/factory.py:580, in               ResourceFactory._create_action.<locals>.do_action(self, *args, **kwargs)
    579 def do_action(self, *args, **kwargs):
--> 580     response = action(self, *args, **kwargs)
    582     if hasattr(self, 'load'):
    583         # Clear cached data. It will be reloaded the next
    584         # time that an attribute is accessed.
    585         # TODO: Make this configurable in the future?
    586         self.meta.data = None

File /opt/conda/envs/Python-RT23.1/lib/python3.10/site-packages/ibm_boto3/resources/action.py:88, in   ServiceAction.__call__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs)
     79 params.update(kwargs)
     81 logger.debug(
     82     'Calling %s:%s with %r',
     83     parent.meta.service_name,
     84     operation_name,
     85     params,
     86 )
---> 88 response = getattr(parent.meta.client, operation_name)(*args, **params)
     90 logger.debug('Response: %r', response)
     92 return self._response_handler(parent, params, response)

File /opt/conda/envs/Python-RT23.1/lib/python3.10/site-packages/ibm_botocore/client.py:401, in ClientCreator._create_api_method.<locals>._api_call(self, *args, **kwargs)
    398     raise TypeError(
    399         "%s() only accepts keyword arguments." % py_operation_name)
    400 # The "self" in this scope is referring to the BaseClient.
--> 401 return self._make_api_call(operation_name, kwargs)

File /opt/conda/envs/Python-RT23.1/lib/python3.10/site-packages/ibm_botocore/client.py:720, in BaseClient._make_api_call(self, operation_name, api_params)
    718 else:
    719     apply_request_checksum(request_dict)
--> 720     http, parsed_response = self._make_request(
    721         operation_model, request_dict, request_context)
    723 self.meta.events.emit(
    724     'after-call.{service_id}.{operation_name}'.format(
    725         service_id=service_id,
   (...)
    728     model=operation_model, context=request_context
    729 )
    731 if http.status_code >= 300:

File /opt/conda/envs/Python-RT23.1/lib/python3.10/site-packages/ibm_botocore/client.py:740, in     BaseClient._make_request(self, operation_model, request_dict, request_context)
    738 def _make_request(self, operation_model, request_dict, request_context):
    739     try:
--> 740         return self._endpoint.make_request(operation_model, request_dict)
    741     except Exception as e:
    742         self.meta.events.emit(
    743             'after-call-error.{service_id}.{operation_name}'.format(
    744                 service_id=self._service_model.service_id.hyphenize(),
    745                 operation_name=operation_model.name),
    746             exception=e, context=request_context
    747         )

File /opt/conda/envs/Python-RT23.1/lib/python3.10/site-packages/ibm_botocore/endpoint.py:107, in  Endpoint.make_request(self, operation_model, request_dict)
    104 def make_request(self, operation_model, request_dict):
    105     logger.debug("Making request for %s with params: %s",
    106                  operation_model, request_dict)
--> 107     return self._send_request(request_dict, operation_model)

File /opt/conda/envs/Python-RT23.1/lib/python3.10/site-packages/ibm_botocore/endpoint.py:180, in Endpoint._send_request(self, request_dict, operation_model)
    178 context = request_dict['context']
    179 self._update_retries_context(context, attempts)
--> 180 request = self.create_request(request_dict, operation_model)
    181 success_response, exception = self._get_response(
    182     request, operation_model, context)
    183 while self._needs_retry(attempts, operation_model, request_dict,
    184                         success_response, exception):

File /opt/conda/envs/Python-RT23.1/lib/python3.10/site-packages/ibm_botocore/endpoint.py:120, in Endpoint.create_request(self, params, operation_model)
    116     service_id = operation_model.service_model.service_id.hyphenize()
    117     event_name = 'request-created.{service_id}.{op_name}'.format(
    118         service_id=service_id,
    119         op_name=operation_model.name)
--> 120     self._event_emitter.emit(event_name, request=request,
    121                              operation_name=operation_model.name)
    122 prepared_request = self.prepare_request(request)
    123 return prepared_request

File /opt/conda/envs/Python-RT23.1/lib/python3.10/site-packages/ibm_botocore/hooks.py:357, in EventAliaser.emit(self, event_name, **kwargs)
    355 def emit(self, event_name, **kwargs):
    356     aliased_event_name = self._alias_event_name(event_name)
--> 357     return self._emitter.emit(aliased_event_name, **kwargs)

File /opt/conda/envs/Python-RT23.1/lib/python3.10/site-packages/ibm_botocore/hooks.py:228, in HierarchicalEmitter.emit(self, event_name, **kwargs)
    217 def emit(self, event_name, **kwargs):
    218     """
    219     Emit an event by name with arguments passed as keyword args.
    220 
   (...)
    226              handlers.
    227     """
--> 228     return self._emit(event_name, kwargs)

File /opt/conda/envs/Python-RT23.1/lib/python3.10/site-packages/ibm_botocore/hooks.py:211, in HierarchicalEmitter._emit(self, event_name, kwargs, stop_on_response)
    209 for handler in handlers_to_call:
    210     logger.debug('Event %s: calling handler %s', event_name, handler)
--> 211     response = handler(**kwargs)
    212     responses.append((handler, response))
    213     if stop_on_response and response is not None:

File /opt/conda/envs/Python-RT23.1/lib/python3.10/site-packages/ibm_botocore/signers.py:93, in   RequestSigner.handler(self, operation_name, request, **kwargs)
     88 def handler(self, operation_name=None, request=None, **kwargs):
     89     # This is typically hooked up to the "request-created" event
     90     # from a client's event emitter.  When a new request is created
     91     # this method is invoked to sign the request.
     92     # Don't call this method directly.
---> 93     return self.sign(operation_name, request)

File /opt/conda/envs/Python-RT23.1/lib/python3.10/site-packages/ibm_botocore/signers.py:157, in RequestSigner.sign(self, operation_name, request, region_name, signing_type, expires_in, signing_name)
    155     kwargs['signing_name'] = signing_context['signing_name']
    156 try:
--> 157     auth = self.get_auth_instance(**kwargs)
    158 except UnknownSignatureVersionError as e:
    159     if signing_type != 'standard':

File /opt/conda/envs/Python-RT23.1/lib/python3.10/site-packages/ibm_botocore/signers.py:237, in RequestSigner.get_auth_instance(self, signing_name, region_name, signature_version, **kwargs)
    235 frozen_credentials = None
    236 if self._credentials is not None:
--> 237     frozen_credentials = self._credentials.get_frozen_credentials()
    238 kwargs['credentials'] = frozen_credentials
    239 if cls.REQUIRES_REGION:

File /opt/conda/envs/Python-RT23.1/lib/python3.10/site-packages/ibm_botocore/credentials.py:2948, in OAuth2Credentials.get_frozen_credentials(self)
   2914 def get_frozen_credentials(self):
   2915     """Return immutable credentials.
   2916 
   2917     The ``access_key``, ``secret_key``, and ``token`` properties
   (...)
   2946 
   2947     """
-> 2948     token = self.token_manager.get_token()
   2950     # Signer is only interested in token, and besides, we might not even have api key
   2951     return ReadOnlyCredentials(
   2952         None, None, token)

File /opt/conda/envs/Python-RT23.1/lib/python3.10/site-packages/ibm_botocore/credentials.py:2490, in DefaultTokenManager.get_token(self)
   2488 try:
   2489     if not self._get_cache_token(): # try again another thread may have refreshed it
-> 2490         self._get_initial_token()
   2491         self._initial_token_set_event.set();
   2493         if self._background_thread:
   2494             # check to see if the thread is still running

File /opt/conda/envs/Python-RT23.1/lib/python3.10/site-packages/ibm_botocore/credentials.py:2686, in DefaultTokenManager._get_initial_token(self, retry_count, retry_delay)
   2684 while True:
   2685     try:
-> 2686         metadata = self.auth_function()
   2687         break
   2688     except Exception as e:

File /opt/conda/envs/Python-RT23.1/lib/python3.10/site-packages/ibm_botocore/credentials.py:2575, in DefaultTokenManager._default_auth_function(self)
   2573 if response.status_code != httplib.OK:
   2574     _msg = 'HttpCode({code}) - Retrieval of tokens from server failed.'.format(code=response.status_code)
-> 2575     raise CredentialRetrievalError(provider=self._get_token_url(), error_msg=_msg)
   2577 return json.loads(response.content.decode('utf-8'))

CredentialRetrievalError: Error when retrieving credentials from https://iam.cloud.ibm.com/identity/token: HttpCode(400) - Retrieval of tokens from server failed.

